# Custom view in fragment overlap other fragment on samsung device

Tags: android, fragment, samsung-mobile, custom-view

I am facing a problem of overlapping fragments when i inflate fragments from below.

[image]
This is code in layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nonAdParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_blur">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/collage_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_blur"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/collageview_margin" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

fragment "collage_view_container" contains 1 custom view and fragment "menu_footer" contains horizontal recyclerview.

This is code programmatically:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.collage_view_container, new CollageContainerFrag().setLayoutModel(model)).commit();

    FooterMenuFragment footerFrag = new FooterMenuFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.no_anim)
            .add(R.id.menu_footer, footerFrag).commit();
```

Issue: Custom view in "collage_view_container" fragment overlap horizontal recyclerview in "menu_footer" fragment on SAMSUNG device solely.
If i config line this code:

```
if (SystemUtils.isSamsungDevice()) {
        getView().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); 
}
```

then issue not appear but app will process "slowly". Otherwise, issues appear again.

This is whole code of view where "nonAdParent" framelayout located-in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout      
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_blur"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/> 

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/adParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nonAdParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_blur">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/collage_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_blur"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/collageview_margin" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

P.S. Please tell if some more code needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.So you should use Relative Layout as your parent layout instead of Frame Layout.

Comment: @sunilkushwah thanks ; i try use RelativeLayout for parent layout instead of FrameLayout, but it NOT works.

Comment: can you share that code where u have used Relative Layout

Comment: @sunilkushwah i edited in post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Frame layout(nonAdParent) part with the code given below

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nonAdParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_blur">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/collage_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_blur"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/collageview_margin" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/collage_view_container"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```